# Create dynamic nested list from JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem understanding this problem. I have this json in a file called list.json for testing purpose. I will be getting this list generated by server later on.

```
[
{
    name    : "ABC",
    id      : "link_abc"
},
{
    name    : "DEF",
    id      : "link_def"
},
{
    name    : "GHI",
    id      : "link_ghi"
},
{
    name    : "JKL",
    id      : "link_jkl"
}

]
```

And here's my javascript to display the list in `<li>` format.

```
$(function(generate_list_from_JSON){
$('a[href="#state"]').click(function(){
    $.getJSON("scripts/list.json", function (obj){
        $.each(obj.name, function (key, value){
            alert(key);
            })
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is, there's nothing displayed, even in console. How do I trap what's sending and what's receiving? I tried `console.log()` but still blank.

Comment: Have you tried settings debug breakpoints within developer console on every line?  This would tell you which piece specifically is not behaving as expected.

Comment: use jsonlint.com to validate your json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires quotation marks around the attribute names.  So you need to do something like this:

```
[
{
    "name"    : "ABC",
    "id"      : "link_abc"
},
...
]
```

JavaScript objects don't require the attribute names to be quoted, but JSON does.

HTH

Comment: This one solves the matter. I can access the attributes, but as @Corey said, I can't do an each for array. I'll find that out in a while. Thanks a bunch guys!

Answer (score 1):

I see few problems:

- Your JSON object is invalid. It is an array of objects but first two objects are not separated with `,` and strings in JSON should be quoted.
- In your javascript code, you are refering to `obj.users`, and your object, even if it would have that `,`, does not have users at all.

Comment: OK. I've updated my question. in regards to your comment. But still nothing.

Comment: @rolodex still obj.name is not defined... use `$.each(obj, function(i,o){console.log(o.name)})` and quote indexes in json.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do an each on obj.name.  obj is an array. Arrays do not have a property named "name" and therefore you'll never enter the loop.

Just loop through obj[0] to obj[obj.length-1].